# Upgrading App to Swift 4 and iOS 11 - TwitterKit Issues

Tags: swift4, twitterkit, ios11.2

I'm trying to upgrade my app to latest iOS support. I've added TwitterKit via CocoaPods, and placed header in my Bridge Header.  However; I am getting an error saying:

> Use of unresolved identified 'Twitter' - did you mean 'TWTRTTwitter'.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions lauunchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"MYKEY", consumerSecret:"MYSECRET")
    return true
}
```

This right out of the Twitter recommended code.  I also get it at:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let handled:Bool = true

    Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)

    return handled
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: How did you add it in your Podfile?

Comment: Here's my pod file:                                                                                           # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.2'

target 'APPNAME' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
 pod 'TwitterKit'

end

Comment: Ok found the first issue, the BridgeHeader was duplicated in the original file and I had added to the wrong one.  Removed the duplicate and updated bridge header with the line #include <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>.   This gives me a File not found error.

Comment: Also added Pods/** to my User Search Path... Still no good.

Comment: well there must be an obvious answer, but I've not gotten this working yet...

Comment: looks like there's an issue with the initialiser...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you, Andy Piper,  I fixed the issue as following:

1. Updated pod so that TwitterCore 3.1.0 and TwitterKit 3.3.0
2. In Bridging-Header.h file

imported as 
TwitterKit/TWTRKit.h instead of 
TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h

3. In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,

   - Modified  Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: ”your consumer key”, consumerSecret:”your consumer secret”)

TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: ”your consumer key”, consumerSecret:”your consumer secret”)

i.e replace Twiter with TWTRTwitter where it is used.

- No need to initialize with fabric, so removed this line or removed

Fabric.with([Twitter.self]) or Fabric.with([TWTRTwitter.self])

Comment: I get "'TwitterKit/TWTRKit.h' file not found" :(

Comment: with bridging #import "TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h" I could use Twitter.sharedInstance() I guess TwitterKit was updated.

Answer (score 5):

There’s a bit of a code change with the latest Twitter Kit release. We changed `Twitter` -> `TWTRTwitter` - but also added a macro so that you should still be able to use `[Twitter sharedInstance]`. Unfortunately, this currently does not work with Swift - so have a try with `TWTRTwitter` as suggested. We'll get this sorted out in the docs! sorry!

Comment: Is this issue fixed? I cannot use Twitterkit with Swift 4. When changed to TWTRTwitter, there is issue and crash on line Fabric.with([TWTRTwitter.self]) saying cannot initialize TWTRTwitter as it is not valid.

Comment: Twitter Kit is not part of Fabric anymore.