# Twitter.sharedInstance() does not exist swift TwitterKit

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, cocoapods, twitterkit

I'm new to Xcode and swift.

I have started to work with TwitterKit, I have installed it on my project using cocoapods, I followed this tutorial: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation

The problem is, when I try to initialize TwitterKit in AppDelegate, I can't use the `Twitter.sharedInstace`, because `Twitter` does not exist. (I've imported the TwitterKit in the AppDelegate using `import TwitterKit`)

Here is my App Delegete class:

```
import UIKit
import TwitterKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"********", consumerSecret:"*******") 
        //Here I get the error: Use of unresolved identifier 'Twitter'       
        return true
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you use cocoapods, you need to open the workspace and not the project. Did you do that?

Comment: When using cocoapods you need to build your project once so the framework is created, then you can start using TwitterKit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading App to Swift 4 and iOS 11 - TwitterKit Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858555/upgrading-app-to-swift-4-and-ios-11-twitterkit-issues)

Comment: Thanks Abdul! This solved the problem!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use Swift 4 you need to use TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance() almost of Twitter.sharedInstance() because Twitter class has been replaced with TWTRTwitter. With Object C you haven't this problem beacause there is a macro that hidden this change. Unfortunately "dev.twitter.com" has not been updated.

Comment: Yes, in objective C, `po [Twitter sharedInstance]` is an unrecognized object and gives an error, and I was wondering why, but `po [TWTRTwitter sharedInstance]` works. Your answer helped me to know to try TWTRTwitter